# Выдача объектов в соответствии с ролью?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2, dto

есть метод у контроллера AdminController

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Admin> GetAdmins() {
    if (User.IsInRole("User")) {
        //возвратить Админа с полями которые доступны этой роли
    } else if (User.IsInRole("Admin")){
        //возвратить Админа со всеми полями
    }
}
```

Как правильнее будет реализовать такую схему ?

Comment: Сделай разные DTO

Comment: @Alex78191 создать, к примеру, класс AdminForUser и в него конвертировать ?

Comment: как конвертировать?

Comment: @Alex78191 в класс AdminForUser передавать объект Admin, и выбирать только нужные поля

Comment: Можно использовать Mapper или создать интерфейс `AdminForUserDTO` с нужными полями и реализовать его в `Admin`.

Comment: @Alex78191 Спасибо ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Можно создать класс [DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331777/how-to-create-a-dto-in-asp-net) `AdminForUserDTO` с разрешенными полями и
   использовать Mapper для конвертации или [вручную инициализировать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5).
2. Можно создать интерфейс `AdminForUserDTO` с нужными полями, реализовать его в `Admin` и приводить класс `Admin` к интерфейсу `AdminForUserDTO` Метод должен возвращать `GetAdmins` должен возвращать тип `object` в этом случае.